# Formatting the number entered in textfield in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter

I have a text field where the user enters a number, which is in the range of thousands.

I want the text field to be formatted as the user enters the number, example :
200000 should become 200,000.

how do i go about doing this??

Many Thanks,

S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same question!

Here's how you do it. You want to use NSNumberFormatter and set it to use Decimal style:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];  
textField.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: [formatter numberFromString:textField.text]];
```

Replace textField with the name of your UITextField variable.